# Any difference between pleasure to us to... vs. pleasure of ours to...?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, phrases, idioms, formality

I am writing a super-formal letter (it is a semi-legal text) and I am unsure if there is any sensible difference between writing

"It is a great pleasure to us to..." (26,200,000 hits on Google)

instead of

"It is a great pleasure of ours to..." (20,300 hits on Google)

The Google-distribution suggests that the second variant might be either

1. Grammatically incorrect; and/or
2. Used only in certain dialects; or
3. More formal than the first variant, and it is rarely used.

Are both expressions correct? If so, why is the second one less popular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google reports

> (1) "great pleasure to us to" 7130K hits
>   (2) "great pleasure to us" 321K hits
>   (3) "great pleasure for us to" 199K hits
>   (4) "great pleasure of ours to" 21.5K

It's hard to explain the stats for (1) and (2).

The Ngram viewer [finds](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great%20pleasure%20to%20us%20to%2Cgreat%20pleasure%20for%20us%20to%2Cgreat%20pleasure%20of%20ours%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreat%20pleasure%20to%20us%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreat%20pleasure%20for%20us%20to%3B%2Cc0) that before about 1945 (1) was more popular than (3), but after 1945 their positions switched.  The viewer finds no instances of (4).

They're all idiomatic and non-colloquial.